# Have FluentValidation call a function with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation for the server side validation. Now I have had it call a function before with Must validation:

```
RuleFor(x => x.UserProfile).Must(ValidateProfile).WithMessage("We are sorry, you have already logged  on " + DateTime.Now + ". Please come again tomorrow.");
```

Now, that works because the only parameter that validateProfile takes is UserProfile. it is all good.

My problem now is that I am trying to have a function with two parameters validate the data.The function which I am trying to use for validation looks like below:

```
bool IsValid(string promocode, IUserProfile userProfile)
```

Now, I am not sure how to bind IsValid to a fluentValidation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Where is promocode coming from? The Must method has overloads accepting `Func<TProp,bool>`, `Func<T,TProp,bool>`, and `Func<T,TProp, PropertyValidatorContext, bool>`

If promocode is a property of the object being validated, it would be easy to pass something like

```
 .RuleFor(x => x.UserProfile).Must( (o, userProfile) => { return IsValid(o.promoCode, userProfile); })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, promocode is a property of object being validated. and also I wanted to show error as promocode error so I made a minor change in the code that you posted.But what you send basically works great. here is my changed code RuleFor(x => x.PromoCode).Must((o, promocode) => IsValid(promocode, o.UserProfile));

Answer (score 6):

```
//with MustAsync

RuleFor(v => v.UserId).MustAsync(
            async (model, userId, cancellation) =>
           {
               return await IsValid(model.PromoCode, userId, cancellation);
           }
         ).WithMessage("{PropertyName} message.");


 private async Task<bool> IsUniqueUserNameAsync(string promoCode, string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```